# Assistance regarding model choice

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Im new to &investigating Machine Learning. I have a use case & data but I am unsure of a few things, mainly how my model will run, and what model to start with. Details of the use case and questions are below. Any advice is appreciated.

My Main question is:

1. When basing a result on scores that are accumulated over time, is it possible to design a model to run on a continuous basis so it gives a best guess at all times, be it run on day one or 3 months into the semester?
2. What model should I start with? I was thinking a classifier, but ranking might be interesting also.

**Use Case Details**

Apprentices take a semesterized course, 4 semesters long, each 6 months in duration. Over the course of a semester, apprentices perform various operations and processes & are scored on how well they do. After each semester, the apprentices either have sufficient score to move on to semester 2, or they fail.

We are investigating building a model that will help identify apprentices who are in danger of failing, with enough time for them to receive help.

Each procedure is assigned a complexity code of simple, intermediate or advanced, and are weighted by complexity.

Regarding Features, we have the following: -

- Initial interview scores
- Entry Exam Scores
- Total number of simple procedures each apprentice performed
- Total number of intermediate procedures each apprentice performed
- Total number of advanced procedures each apprentice performed
- Average score for each complexity level
- Demograph information (nationality, age, gender)

I am unsure of is how the model will work and when we will run it. i.e. - if we run it on day one of the semester, I assume everyone will fail as everyone has procedure scores of 0

Current plan is to run the model 2-3 months into each semester, so there is enough score data & also enough time to help any apprentices who are in danger of failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely looks like a classification model problem:

```
y = f(x[0],x[1], ..., x[N-1])
```

where `y (boolean output) = {pass, fail}` and `x[i]` are different features.

There is a plethora of ML classification models like Naive Bayes, Neural Networks, Decision Trees, etc. which can be used depending upon the type of the data. In case you are looking for an answer which suggests a particular ML model, then I would need more data for the same. However, in general, this [flow-chart](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) can be helpful in selection of the same. You can also read about Model Selection from Andrew-Ng's CS229's [5th lecture](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes5.pdf).

Now coming back to the basic methodology, some of these features like initial interview scores, entry exam scores, etc. you already know in advance. Whereas, some of them like performance in procedures are known over the semester.

So, **there is no harm in saying that the model will always predict better towards the end of each semester**.

However, I can make a few suggestions to make it even better:

- Instead of taking the initial procedure-scores as 0, take them as a mean/median of the past performances in other procedures by the subject-apprentice.
- You can even build a sub-model to analyze the relation between procedure-scores and interview-scores as they are not completely independent. (I will explain this sentence in the later part of the answer)
- However, if the semester is very first semester of the subject-apprentice, then you won't have such data already present for that apprentice. In that case, you might need to consider the average performances of other apprentices with similar profiles as the subject-apprentice. If the data-set is not very large, [K Nearest Neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) approach can be quite useful here. However, for large data-sets, KNN suffers from the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).
- Also, plot a graph between `y` and different variables `x[i]`, so as to see the independent variation of y with respect to each variable.
- Most probably (although it's just a hypotheses), y will depend more the initial variables in comparison the variables achieved later. The reason being that **the later variables are not completely independent of the former variables**.
- My point is, if a model can be created to predict the output of a semester, then, a similar model can be created to predict just the output of the 1st procedure-test.
- In the end, as the model might be heavily based on demographic factors and other things, it might not be a very successful model. For the same reason, we cannot accurately predict election results, soccer match results, etc. As they are heavily dependent upon real-time dynamic data.
- For dynamic predictions based on different procedure performances, [Time Series Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series) can be a bit helpful. But in any case, the final result will heavily dependent on the apprentice's continuity in motivation and performance which will become more clear towards the end of each semester.

Comment: fantastic insight, thank you!
multiple models, one for brand new students with no results yet, and another for students that have results, and a disclaimer that the more results present, the more accurate the results.

You make a good point that the demographic features may outweigh all else, but the fact that apprentices have to have a passing score in an exam & a passing score in an interview means theres a good chance they are decent performers, and after that its down to how they do through the semester. I'll get my data in order and just try a few models to start with. thanks!

Comment: ^ Exactly what I meant to convey. Glad that it help :)